# Can accept() return without getting a connection?

Tags: sockets

I have a blocking TCP socket, which is blocking at the `accept()` call. Is it possible to make the `accept()` call return (other than by getting a connection from a client)? This is for closing the socket as part of system shutdown and exiting the thread which is accepting the connections.

Comment: Make it a non-blocking socket..?

Answer (score 4):

1) In a single threaded program you can use a signal from another process. Make sure you do NOT pass the SA_RESTART flag when installing signal handler.

2) If you need to stop `accept()` from another thread of the same process, create a socketpair or pipe and block on `select()` on your socket and this pipe. When you need to unblock, write something to the pipe.

3) Or just use `select()` with some small timeout (1 second) and poll the exit flag each time it returns.

Answer (score 2):

Use SOCK_NONBLOCK in the flags parameter : http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/2/accept.htm

Comment: @Maanu has blocking socket, this will make it non blocking

Comment: Actually, this will only affect the new client sockets. You want to use this flag on the initial server socket when you create it: http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket

Answer (score 0):

In windows, WSA will cancel accept (accept will return INVALID_SOCKET) if you close accepting connection (call closesocket()).